# Baggage delayed/lost for more than 21 days - how high is the reimbursement?

Tags: compensation, lost-luggage, scandinavia, sas

I flew with SAS within europe (destination was OSL) and had a connecting flight to Asia with another airline (different bookings).

On my SAS flight my checked baggage was delayed and didn't make it to my connecting flight to Asia (even though I had a 6+ hours layover). A Property Irregularity Report was filed in OSL.

Now, after 22 days, I still have not received my baggage in Asia. There were many messages sent to SAS, 99% from my side. The world tracer system does not have updated information and it seems like the baggage is in a different country than I am.

=> Stated by the Montreal Convention I have the right of a reimbursement of up to 1,131 SDR.
Can I just file a complaint with that amount without having any recipes of whats actually in my baggage? 
The baggage and the contents of it may be valued around 300 €, but I obviously not have receipts for all the stuff inside.

Can I just ask for 300, 500, 800, 1000 € without any recipes? What is the normal procedure? I am really disappointed in how SAS handled that case and want to get the most out of it.

Comment: Did SAS agree to send your luggage to Asia? As you only had a booking to Oslo with them, their responsibility would usually end after delivery of the luggage in Oslo.

Comment: "and had a connecting flight to Asia with another airline (different bookings)" It's either the same booking, or it's not a connecting flight. Instead, it's just two unrelated trips. The airline's responsibility is to deliver your luggage to the next stopping place on the same ticket. The airline is entitled to some kind of proof of the value of the contents of your luggage. Claiming for 1000 EUR for 300 EUR of loss is criminally fraudulent. The "normal procedure" for a Montreal claim starts with a written demand but may need to escalate to legal proceedings.

Comment: Yes, they did. First they said they will try to put the baggage to my connecting flight with the different airline, but my baggage arrived too late in OSL.

After I arrived in Singapore I gave them my temporary address there. But because I only stayed there for 3 days, my baggage didn't arrive on time.

Now Im in Thailand and my baggage is at the airport in Singapore (according to the tracking system and emails from SAS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update (for anyone interested): I received my luggage after 23 days (so basically *too* late), but everything was inside and fine.

I still sent them my receipts for the taxi ride to the airport (had to pick up the bag), some cosmetic stuff and medicine (eye drops).

They paid for everything except the eye drops cause it is considered medicine. The total amount was only around 70 Euros for everything (including around 10 for eyedrops).

Basically I'm happy, cause I got my stuff back and got reimbursed.